# What is the technique behind live streaming from security camera to web pages when using Java?

Tags: java, video, camera, live-streaming, security-camera

I have done researches on Google, many posts and answers gave me ready-to-use packages or the example is not in Java. I am not looking for solutions to this question.

I want to understand how live streaming from security camera on the web pages can be implemented and in Java.

First of all, there is no video file recorded beforehand because it is about live streaming from security camera. But one should be able to watch the video later on as well.

My questions are:

1. Do I always need to record the video first and use that video on the web page so that video can be live-streamed and can be watched later on? Or live streaming and video recording/saving in a file can be in two separate processes?
2. Is WebSocket Server the only solution to push video data to the web browser continuously?
3. In case of WebSocket Server pusing video data to the web browser, what kind of data should be pushed to the web browser?
4. On the web page, must I use the `<img>` tag to show the live-streaming video?

Solution 1: From the post below, the Java WebSocket Server pushes the ByteBuffer object containing byte data to the web browser. But this solution first takes video data from the web browser (client), sends the data to the WebSocket Server and then just receives the converted version of data back. It is like a round trip.
https://javawebsocketsvideo.blogspot.com/

Solution 2: And this code sample shows that Java Server sends DatagramPacket object containing byte data to its client. But this solution works with existing video file (not live-streaming) and its client is not a web page.
https://github.com/ramanbuttar/video-streaming/blob/master/Server.java

That's why these solutions did not clear my questions.

Comment: Search google for HLS and DASH

Comment: I'm hoping the two "re-open" votes have a possible solution (but cannot answer a closed Question) so I'm voting to re-open...

Comment: Thanks @VC.One! Do you have any answer for this question?